# SDwebimage cannot get image from an unverified https

Tags: https, sdwebimage

I question for my ios app development.
I used sdwebimage to get some image from my own server which is a https one.
However, i did not buy a certificate and the server address was not verified.
Therefore, the app failed to get the image. I've tried to get an image from amazon via https. It worked.

Is there any configuration should I do to my app so that it could get the image from my server?

thanks

Comment: Which *"app"* are you referring to? Go to *let's encrypt* if you need a free certificate.

Comment: It's an iOS App. I am looking at the website you suggested. Maybe it could solve my problem. thanks